# Finding when will the sequence reach 4600

Tags: sequences-and-series

> \begin{align}
>   & B_0  = 0, \\
>   & B_{n + 1}  = B_{n} \cdot 1.0075 + 95.
>   \end{align}

I am able to come up with the above formula from the first $4$ terms.

But next I need to find out the $B_n = 4600$.

In other words, when the number is $4600$ what's the $n$?

What formula/strategy should I use to solve it?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C_n=B_n+D$, and I will choose $D$ to make the recursion simple.
$C_{n+1}=B_{n+1}+D=(C_n-D)*1.0075+95+D.$
Choose $D$ so that $95-0.0075D=0$, then $C_{n+1}=C_n*1.0075$.
$C_n=A(1.0075)^n$, and choose A so that $A=C_0=B_0+D=D$.
Lastly, solve $C_n=4600+D$

Comment: I don't understand how you get $C_n = B_n +D$, would you mind to explain it to me?

Comment: The homogeneous equation is $B_{n+1}=B_n*1.0075$ where you ignore the $+95$.  It has the solution $B_n=A(1.0075)^n$.  There is also a particular solution, which resembles $+95$ and lacks the $(1.0075)^n$.  The particular solution is $B_n=D$, which resembles $+95$ because it is constant.  Then you have $D=1.0075D+95$.  The final solution puts the two together.  Sadly, the $D$ in this comment is the negative of the $D$ in my answer.

Comment: okey, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Repeatedly writing out the given relation shows that
\begin{eqnarray*}
B_n&=&1.0075B_{n-1}+95=1.0075(1.0075B_{n-2}+95)+95=\ldots\\
&=&1.0075^nB_0+1.0075^{n-1}\times95+1.0075^{n-2}\times95+\ldots+1.0075^1\times95+95\\
&=&1.0075^n\times0+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}1.0075^i\times95=95\times\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}1.0075^i.
\end{eqnarray*}
This last sum is a geometric sum, for which we have the closed form
$$95\times\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}1.0075^i.=95\times\frac{1.0075^n-1}{1.0075-1}=(1.0075^n-1)\times12666.66\ldots.$$
Now setting this equal to $4600$ yields $n\approx41.46$.